# Once I have closed CMD how do I run again manage.py runserver again?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home')
]
```

I have setup Django in Pycharm and it worked fine. But now I have closed the CMD and restarted pycharm and I don't find a way to rerun it again. How should I start the run server again so it can show my app on http://localhost:8000/.

Do I have to go through the whole big process again or is there any code or something I can write in CMD so it can again run the server and start the app

like earlier I was doing manage.py runserver

If I do `C:\Users\admin>python manage.py runserver` I get:

> python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: what is wrong with doing `python manage.py runserver` like you did before?

Comment: You should be able to set up Pycharm such that when you click the "Run" button it will start the server for you.

Comment: Generally this is what you should be doing. Surely pressing the up arrow key a few times or using Ctrl+r to search for commands you ran recently can't be that hard, can it?

If you are however that reluctant to do it, run your application through apache with mod_wsgi or inside a docker container or something.

Comment: Don't close the `cmd` window to quit the server, just terminate the process.

Comment: Now I closed and when I do  C:\Users\admin>python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory